# Taking arg from user and finding the correct ID

Tags: python

arg1 = any of the countries in the list I have going. User chooses these.

arg2 = any of the countries in the list I have going. User chooses these.

```
ukraine = '1'
russia = '0'
finland = '2'
sweden = '3'
usa = '5'
api_key = "xxxxx"
    
resp = requests.get(f"https://hidden.ee/i.php?api_key={api_key}&action=na&country={arg1}country2={arg2}")

print(resp.url)
```

Only thing I get correct is the API key and not the arg1 or arg2. Is there a way to look up and compare if arg1/2 matches in my list please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to look up the country id based on the name passed into the arguments

```py
arg1 = 'ukraine'
arg2 = 'sweden'
# use a dictionary to look up the country
countries = {
    'ukraine': '1',
    'russia': '0',
    'finland': '2',
    'sweden': '3',
    'usa': '5',
}
# assign the country to its id based on the dictionary
country1 = countries[arg1]
country2 = countries[arg2]

api_key = 'xxxxx'

url = f'https://hidden.ee/i.php?api_key={api_key}&action=na&country={country1}country2={country2}'

# check out the url
print(url)
```

Output:

```
https://hidden.ee/i.php?api_key=xxxxx&action=na&country=1country2=3
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. Appreciate you clearing up my logic.